# How to use svelte:component with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I would like to use a dynamic component to select a view depending on the value of an enum:

```html
<svelte:component
  this={components[enumValue]}
  {...props}
/>
```

But I don't get a compile error if I don't pass all the necessary parameters:

```html
<svelte:component
  this={components[enumValue]}
/>
```

How to correctly specify the typing of dynamic components?

---

UPD: map example with React

```
const props: Props = {...}
const components: Record<EnumType, React.FC<Props>> = {
  [EnumType.variant_1]: Component1,
  [EnumType.variant_2]: Component2,
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can apply a little indirection using a generic wrapper component. E.g.

```html
<!-- renderer.svelte -->
<script lang="ts" generics="C extends ComponentType">
    import type { ComponentType, ComponentProps } from 'svelte';

    export let component: C;
    export let props: ComponentProps<InstanceType<C>>;
</script>

<svelte:component this={component} {...props} />
```

Usage example:

```html
<!-- adder.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    export let a: number;
    export let b: number;
</script>

{a} + {b} = {a + b}
```

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Renderer from './renderer.svelte';
    import Adder from './adder.svelte';
</script>

<Renderer component={Adder} />
<!-- Error on "Renderer" because props are missing -->

<Renderer component={Adder} props={{ a: 12 }} />
<!-- Error on "props": Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }'
                       but required in type '{ a: number; b: number; }' -->
```

This may require very recent versions of `svelte`/`svelte-preprocess` to work correctly with the generics. You could also drop the generics and type the renderer's properties more loosely. Having `props` as an export of another component at the very least ensures the props missing error.

Comment: Thanks, your example works! To solve my problem, it remains to get the components type with the desired type of parameters. For example, in React it can be solved with React.FC type like in UPD. I can't find any example how to get Svelte component type.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how to use keywords "bind", "on", "use" in this case

Comment: You probably will not be able to use every feature when doing something like this. You will not be able to use `bind` in any case, if you spread properties. In general using `svelte:component` should be a rare occurrence, so you should pick your trade-offs. What is UPD? Also, you already have the "component type", it is what you import from a Svelte file.

Comment: If you want to get the type from within a component, that is currently not supported ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5517)).

Comment: `SvelteComponentTyped` is now deprecated and I cannot get this proposed solution to work - any ideas? (using Svelte 4.2.1)

Comment: @Einar: I updated the answer to reflex current syntax/types.